# Is it possible to differentiate between reply-to and sender email with mailchimp ? (having programmed a 3rd party system)

Tags: mailchimp

I am using mailchimp as a MA-system/toolbox for our company customers (i.e offered as a service for our customers). So the customer is entering lists and campaigns details into a 3rd party program which then via API gets added to mailchimp and then eventually sent out.

But when they enter their reply/from email mailchimp will refuse to send out the campaign due to being non verified. Fair enough, but can i somehow go around that problem ? Like using my verfied email as the sender but still be able to have my customer email as the reply-to field (as is a valid MIME header field) ?

If not, how are other 3rd party software solving the "on-behalf of" problem when sending out marketing emails for their customers without using a real reply-to email which goes to your actual customer (and not mine)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible, as far as I know. You can have your customers create their own MailChimp accounts, or create your own for them. You can also just have different lists for each customer; each individual list can have its own default from address.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i suspected that. But i have one question about different list you mentioned. I have that scenario but even then when i specify the reply-to adress mailchimp is complaining about non verified email even in the lists setting. Are you saying that if i specify my customers email in "his/her" list (with the subscribers) i can have that to be the campaign email ?

Mailgun seems to expose up the entire MIME header fields via API. I think it is a bad move from Mailchimp on a trusted Api key (permitted sender) not allowed to set reply-to email.

Comment: Ok i think i got it concerning list and customer email. You will place it in the footer which is good enough for me ...however...the api for create list does not support email as field for contact!

http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/#create-post_lists

As it is now it seems to have taken my mailchimp account email in a lists but it need to set it via the API.

Comment: If you want an email to be from a particular address, you have to verify that domain. Without this, someone would be able to pretend to be, say, billgates@microsoft.com and send out some scam email. It's really a restriction being imposed by email clients (like gmail) who are way more likely to send an email to spam if there's no permission granted. This is true even if you change the address on a campaign-by-campaign basis.